# Ubuntu 16.10 - Secondary Drive

Tags: hard-drive, unity-dash, search

I have Ubuntu 16.10 installed on an SSD drive. I have a secondary drive where I have several files. It's being mounted automatically in mnt/storage but it is considered as an external device. So, dash does not search in it when looking for files. Is there something that can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

Log in as root:

```
exec sudo -i
```

Identify the disk partition:

```
fdisk -l
```

Suppose it is `/dev/sdb1`, create the directory where to mount it `~/Data`:

```
mkdir /home/user/Data
```

Make your user the owner

```
chown -R user-name /home/user/Data
```

Find the uuid of the partition to mount:

```
blkid /dev/sdb1
```

Suppose it is:

```
/dev/sdb1: UUID="10b4bb49-326f-4fef-973e-4feb1e3a17ba" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7a028e88-01"
```

Edit your file `/etc/fstab`:

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the lines to mount the partition `/dev/sdb1`, assuming it is `ext4` file system:

```
# /home/user/Data was on /dev/sdb1
UUID=10b4bb49-326f-4fef-973e-4feb1e3a17ba /home/user/Data  ext4    defaults        0       2
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>  Save File

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>  Close Nano

Continue running:

```
mount -a
```

Your secondary disk should be mounted in `~/Data` ready to use.

Comment: Thank you it worked. However, all I had to do was create the folder and own it. Then simply edit the path in the /etc/fstab since it was already mounted.